# Google Vision AI set monthly quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Is there any way to set a monthly quota for Google Vision AI?
Right now I'm able to find quotas only for:

- requests per minute;
- requests per user per minute.

I just want to be sure that I won't spend more than a predefined number of dollars for this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up [billing alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) so that you are notified. You can break it down by Product, including Vision API.

There's no way to have Vision API automatically block all requests once reaching a certain dollar amount. However you could [listen for budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify) and have your app react accordingly.